# RoutedEvent handler is okay but design view won't load

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I created a routed event ItemSelectedEvent from MyMenu.xaml.cs (an user control), which is part of another user control UserControl1. In the UserControl1.xaml, I have

```
<UserControl
...
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:"MyNameSpace"
local:MyMenu.ItemIsSelected= "ItemIsSelected" >
```

My program actually runs fine and I am getting the event in ItemIsSelected. The problem is XAML keeps saying:

```
The attachable property 'ItemIsSelected' was not found in type 'MyMenu'
```

In my MyMenu.xaml.cs, I have:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent ItemSelectedEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "ItemIsSelected", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler), 
        typeof(UserControl));

public event RoutedEventHandler ItemIsSelected
    {
        add { AddHandler(ItemSelectedEvent , value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ItemSelectedEvent , value); }
    }
```

The error shows "Problem Loading" in the design view. As soon as I removed the line "local:MyMenu....", everything works fine.

Notice that I made a error in my previous post. I changed it to (it's the **event handling method name**, not the event):

```
local:MyMenu.ItemIsSelected= "ItemIsSelected"
```

I am trying to do event bubbling similar to [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/vblasberg/archive/2010/03/30/wpf-routed-events-bubbling-several-layers-up.aspx)

Comment: try clean-building your project and then reload the designer

Comment: I cleaned the project and then rebuild it. Still no luck :(

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Either close the tab in visual studio and load it again. That would force the designer to reload or you can try to change the owner type of your attached event into the name of your UserControl. Dont use the raw UserControl itself and prented its the owner of you attached event. Designer might not like that. Might...

Comment: @OmegaMan Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on WPF Trace Settings specifically `Routed Events` and run in debug mode and check the output window. That *may* give you a hint as to what is happening as to why VS can't properly understand the routing.

Tools-> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> WPF Trace Settings -> Routed Events.

Comment: I changed the setting to All. But thing about ItemSelectedEvent was reported.

Comment: @Martin Since the routed event originates in a base control, possibly change the derived control to send its own routed event after catching the base control event; not the answer I like...but a thought.